# Heroku Asks for PG gem when I have Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, mongodb, heroku

I'm receiving the following error

```
Please install the postgresql adapter: `gem install activerecord-postgresql-adapter` (pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.) (LoadError)
```

whenever I visit a page in my heroku app. I have no idea why this is happening since I'm using MongoDB and Mongoid in my app. I've also added MongoLab Starter as an heroku add on to modify the app for MongoDB. I deleted my GemFile.lock and bundle installed again. My GemFile is

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.0.0'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

gem 'unicorn'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem "slim-rails", "~> 2.0.1"

# For database stuff
gem "bcrypt-ruby", "~> 3.0.1"

gem "american_date", "~> 1.1.0"

gem "mongoid", "~> 3.1.4"

gem "mongoid_spacial", "~> 0.2.16"

gem "mongoid-paperclip", "~> 0.0.8"

gem "aws-s3", "~> 0.6.3"

gem "aws-sdk", "~> 1.8.4"
```

I do not have a database.yml file but I do have a mongoid.yml file. What did I do wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Postgres is the default database for Heroku rails apps.

Comment: Yes, I know. But I've added MongoLab Starter as an add-on to heroku, meaning it can handle MongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Heroku supports MongoDB by "default". Try adding the MongoHD add-on and configuring Mongoid:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mongohq#adding-a-mongohq-database

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've actually added MongoLab Starter.